# How does Islam and the Quran view a non-believer like me?

Tags: quran, sharia, islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis

I am a Western Buddhist with a background in philosophy and theology. I don't believe in God as the first cause, but I do acknowledge it as a metaphor or way of speaking about the transcendent. So I don't completely reject the idea of a revealed God, only relatively as a conventional truth, but truth nonetheless.

I admire Muslims for their virtue, righteousness, and devotion. Overall, I find their worldview beautiful and compassionate. I wanted to ask how Islam and the Quran interpret someone like me, a non-believer.

Thank you.